# Polymer and Disqus on Firefox: Argument 1 of Window.getComputedStyle does not implement interface Element

Tags: firefox, polymer, jekyll, disqus

I'm currently building a website using `Polymer` framework and `Jekyll`. I've added the `Disqus` block in the bottom of the page and it works perfectly in `Chrome` browser.

```
{% if site.disqus %}
<div class="comments">
    <div id="disqus_thread"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var disqus_shortname = '{{ site.disqus }}';
        var disqus_identifier = "{{ page.url }}";

        (function() {
            var dsq = document.createElement('script'); dsq.type = 'text/javascript'; dsq.async = true;
            dsq.src = '//' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js';
            (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);
        })();
    </script>
    <noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view the <a href="http://disqus.com/?ref_noscript">comments powered by Disqus.</a></noscript>
    <a href="http://disqus.com" class="dsq-brlink">comments powered by <span class="logo-disqus">Disqus</span></a>
</div>
{% endif %}
```

But when I open it on `Firefox 35.0.1` I receive the following message in console:

```
TypeError: Argument 1 of Window.getComputedStyle does not implement interface Element.
```

and `Disqus` comments don't load. I've found the same behavior for `Disqus` comments on [Polymer docs website](https://www.polymer-project.org/articles/spa.html), so you can check it out. Any ideas how it can be fixed? Or this is a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was running into this exact issue, and came across this thread:

https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/issues/89

*Mikanoshi* provides a helpful gist at the end of the thread that illustrates a fix:

```
var disqus_shortname = ''; /* Your shortname */
var DISQUS = ...           /* From the start of DISQUS' embed.js */

(function(document) {
    DISQUS.define(...      /* The rest of DISQUS' embed.js */
})(wrap(document));
```

Unfortunate that we have to modify DISQUS' embed.js, but it seems to work!

An explanation of why this is necessary is here: http://webcomponents.org/polyfills/shadow-dom/ (under wrap and unwrap).

Comment: Weird, but seems it is the only way to make it work on FF, thanks!